# Chaining multiple dialogs using context.call/done

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have a LuisDialog which calls a particular dialog if an intent is found. There,on the basis of entity extracted, I am calling another dialog, which seems to be throwing some unhandled exception.
Here is the intent in my root LuiDialog calling BuyDialog(I'm saving the LuisResult for later use)-

```
[LuisIntent("Buy")]
public async Task Buy(IDialogContext context,  LuisResult result)
{
   var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   await context.PostAsync("you want to buy");
   context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<LuisResult>("luis", result);
   context.Call(new BuyDialog(), ResumeAfterBuyDialog);
}
 private  async Task ResumeAfterBuyDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
    {
        var success = await result;
        if (success)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("How else can I help you?");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
          }
    }
```

Here is my BuyDialog calling another dialog(BookDialog) if entity contains "book" string-

```
else if(is_book)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("You selected book category");
                    context.Call(new BookDialog(),BookFormComplete);
                    context.Done(true);
                }
 private async Task BookFormComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)  
    {
        var BookResult = await result;
        //do something if result is true
    }
```

And here is my BookDialog-

```
[Serializable]
public class BookDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public  async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        if (message.Text == "mtl100")
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Correct");
            context.Done(true);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Please enter valid course code");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
```

I know the problem is in that second context.call(the call to bookDialog), because if I remove it the code works perfectly fine. Right now, I'm getting "sorry, my bot code is having an issue" when it reaches there. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `context.Done(true)` that you are doing in the second dialog must be in the `BookDialog` `ResumeAfter<T>` method (`BookFormComplete`)

The 'Is Book' path should looks like:

```
else if(is_book)
{
    await context.PostAsync("You selected book category");
    context.Call(new BookDialog(),BookFormComplete);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!...By the way, is there a way to know where the error originated through emulator itself? I read something about Chain.DefaultIfException method to do this, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: See if this is useful https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#look-for-exceptions. Please upvote the answer if it was useful